# ngx-bootstrap nested dropdowns item binding

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I use ngx-bootstrap nested dropdowns. Here is the code from [ngx-bootstrap nested dropdowns](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns)

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown [autoClose]="false" container="body">
 <button id="button-nested" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
       aria-controls="dropdown-nested">
 This dropdown has nested submenu <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
<ul id="dropdown-nested" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"
   role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-nested">
 <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">Action</a></li>

<li role="menuitem" dropdown triggers="mouseover" placement="right" container="body">
  <a dropdownToggle class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
     (click)="false">Hover me for nested dropdown 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">aaa0</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">aaa1</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">aaa2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li role="menuitem" dropdown triggers="mouseover" placement="right" container="body">
  <a dropdownToggle class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
     (click)="false">Hover me for nested dropdown 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">bbb0</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">bbb1</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">bbb2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
<li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">Separated link</a></li>
```

The question is that all the menu items are hard coded. I want to bind them with the dynamic values. So in ts code.

```
MenuItems: any;
this.MenuItems.push('Hover me for nested dropdown 1');
this.MenuItems.push('Hover me for nested dropdown 2');
```

Now I applied it to ui element.

```
<ul id="dropdown-nested" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"
 role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-nested" *ngFor='let item of MenuItems'>
```

However I got the error:

> only one structural directive can be applied

So what is the work around about it?

**update:**

If the object is complexed, how to do that?
For example:

```
[{
id: '0001',
type: 'donut1',
name: 'Cake1',
ppu: '0.55',
batters:
    {
        batter:
            [
                { id: '1001', type: 'Regular1' },
                { id: '1002', type: 'Chocolate1' },
                { id: '1003', type: 'Blueberry1' },
                { id: '1004', type: 'Devils Food1' }
            ]
    },
topping:
    [
        { id: '5001', type: 'None1' },
        { id: '5002', type: 'Glazed1' },
        { id: '5005', type: 'Sugar1' },
        { id: '5007', type: 'Powdered Sugar1' },
        { id: '5006', type: 'Chocolate with Sprinkles1' },
        { id: '5003', type: 'Chocolate1' },
        { id: '5004', type: 'Maple1' }
    ]
  },
  {
      id: '0002',
      type: 'donut2',
      name: 'Cake2',
      ppu: '0.55',
      batters:
       {
           batter:
            [
                { id: '1001', type: 'Regular2' },
                { id: '1002', type: 'Chocolate2' },
                { id: '1003', type: 'Blueberry2' },
                { id: '1004', type: 'Devils Food2' }
            ]
       },
    topping:
    [
        { id: '5001', type: 'None2' },
        { id: '5002', type: 'Glazed2' },
        { id: '5005', type: 'Sugar2' },
        { id: '5007', type: 'Powdered Sugar2' },
        { id: '5006', type: 'Chocolate with Sprinkles2' },
        { id: '5003', type: 'Chocolate2' },
        { id: '5004', type: 'Maple2' }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your json, it seems like you want a nested dropdown inside a nested dropdown. So, for your json I think the below code should work for you :

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown [autoClose]="false" container="body">
    <button id="button-nested" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
       aria-controls="dropdown-nested">
 This dropdown has nested submenu <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
    <ul id="dropdown-nested" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-nested">


        <li role="menuitem" dropdown triggers="mouseover" placement="right" container="body"
            *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
            <a dropdownToggle class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
                (click)="false">{{item.name}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li role="menuitem" dropdown triggers="mouseover" placement="right" container="body">
                    <a dropdownToggle class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
                        (click)="false">batters<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li role="menuitem" dropdown triggers="mouseover" placement="right" container="body"
                            *ngFor="let batter of item.batters.batter">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" (click)="false">{{batter.type}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li role="menuitem" dropdown triggers="mouseover" placement="right" container="body">
                    <a dropdownToggle class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
                        (click)="false">toppings<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li role="menuitem" dropdown triggers="mouseover" placement="right" container="body"
                            *ngFor="let topping of item.topping">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" (click)="false">{{topping.type}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It works out. There is a little thing. If I click the item then it is vanished. Maybe we need to add `[AutoClose]` attribute?

Comment: Also you had hard code here. For example, `batters` and `toppings`. It is supposed not hard coded. I hope that there is a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all items to be dropdowns then the below code will work.

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown [autoClose]="false" container="body">
 <button id="button-nested" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
       aria-controls="dropdown-nested">
 This dropdown has nested submenu <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
<ul id="dropdown-nested" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"
   role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-nested">
 

<li role="menuitem" dropdown triggers="mouseover" placement="right" container="body" *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
  <a dropdownToggle class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
     (click)="false">{{item}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">bbb0</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">bbb1</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">bbb2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ui>
</div>
```

And if you want some items to be link and others to be nested dropdown then you can use ngIf Else inside li.

Also, for your error you can use **ng-container** or **ng-template** if you want to use more than one structrual directive.

Comment: You code is working for the first level menu, but how to deal with the sub menus? I want to loop the nested array in each item. I updated the question, the array is little complicated.